# Colab: Cannot output Tensorboard in cell anymore

Tags: python, output, jupyter, google-colaboratory, tensorboard

In google colab when running the following code in a cell, without changing the rest of the code, I used to be able to output the tensorboard's ui about a week ago but now the output is blank! I made sure the directory I used exists so that's not the issue...I am also using tensorflow v2 which is the default. Can someone tell me if they also have the same issue or it's just me?

```
%reload_ext tensorboard  # the same for %load_ext
%tensorboard --logdir "insert my dir"
```

Comment: tensorboard works fine for me in colab

Comment: What browser are you using? I'm using Chrome Version 94.0.4606.61 but the issue seems to disappear when using Edge.

Comment: Version 91.0.4472.124

Comment: Downgrading didn't fix it. I noticed that everytime I ran the cell with the above code I get an error in Chrome which I don't get in Edge:
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: t.replace is not a function
    at HTMLIFrameElement.set (<anonymous>:5:5482)
    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (VM521 output_binary.js:1), <anonymous>:6:24)

Comment: Is this because tensorboard dev already shut down?